# How to customize Ofbiz Point Of Sale?

Tags: erp, ofbiz, opentaps

I would like to have dynamic categories and products listing on ofbiz pos instead of static products.
I would like to customize look and feel of current pos.
I have tried changing it from the xmls, but haven't succeeded.
I would really appreciate if somebody could guide me in the right directions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

POS available in OFBiz is actually for demo purpose only. You can create your own POS system by using any other web technologies and can call POS API's available in OFBiz.

HTH.